# In Lucene 4.8.0 SearchManager.MaybeRefresh or DirectoryReader.openIfchange() is not work

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

When I do a little changes to the index. On the surface, the index file structure has not changed. But in fact, the index does change. It is because when there are great changes to the index, the index file structure may be change.

Then SearchManager, MaybeRefresh or DirectoryReader.openIfchange didn't work. It return the old indexsearch. Whether the index file structure must be changed so that they can work?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem. Sorry! I make a mistake.